# Chained references in PHP

Tags: php, reference

I trying to understand PHP reference, but I found a problem, when working with chained references.

```
class A
{
    public $val;

    public function __construct($val)
    {
        $this->val = $val;
    }
}

$values = array(
    'a' => new A('a'),
    'b' => new A('b'),
    'c' => new A('c')
);

$values['a'] = &$values['b'];
$values['b'] = &$values['c'];
```

Return:

```
array(
'a' => new A('b'),
'b' => new A('c'),
'c' => new A('c')
)
```

Why 'val' in object A for key 'a' is 'b'? I expected that value will be 'c'. Thanks

Comment: I think `b` and `c` would need to be set first, otherwise there's nothing for each reference to point to. Try initialising them in the first line with dummy values?

Comment: You cannot just alter your question in such a drastic way. Any comment or answer is immediately wrong or at least confusing for future visitors.

Comment: Actually, I think your first question was better anyway: mixing objects and reference variables like this just confuses the matter, but the fundamental principle is the same.

Comment: I added some additional info to my answer, be sure to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid references, they may get you in hard-to-debug troubles. Also, objects are referenced behind the scenes; that means this:

```
$a1 = new A('a');
$a2 = $a1;
```

is *similar* to:

```
$b1 = new A('a');
$b2 = &$b1;
```

In the way, that:

```
$a2->val = 1; // $a1->val is now equal to 1, because $a1 and $a2 are pointing 
              // to the same instance
$b2->val = 1; // $b1->val is now equal to 1, because $b2 points to $b1
```

There is a subtle difference though:

```
$a1 = 1; // $a2 still points to A object
$b1 = 1; // $b2 still points to $a1 which points to number 1,
         // therefore $b2 == 1
```

Also it works a bit differently with arrays because array assignment always involves value copying.

If you want to understand what is happening in your example, let's take a look:

So your original array is this:

```
$values = array(
    'a' => new A('a'),
    'b' => new A('b'),
    'c' => new A('c')
);
```

Let's take a look what happens in there step by step:

```
$values['a'] = &$values['b']; // $values['a'] is now reference to new A('b')
                              // that means your original new A('a') is now
                              // lost

$values['b'] = &$values['c']; // $values['b'] is now reference to new A('c')
                              // stored under 'c' key, that means $values['b']
                              // is now equal to $values['c'] ; note that this is 
                              // different than $b2 = &$b1; from the above example
                              // since we use an array and not bare variables
                              // the $values['a'] points to value stored under 
                              // the 'b' key, but we replace the 'b' key value 
                              // as opposed to giving it a new value; 
                              // "Array assignment always involves value copying."

// So you ended up with this result:
array(
  'a' => new A('b'),
  'b' => new A('c'), // this is actually reference to 'c', just wrote new A() 
                     // to keep this part consistent with your question's
                     // formatting
  'c' => new A('c') 
)
```

Comment: Beware of statements like "objects are referenced by default" - objects have an *extra* level of indirection, which is independent of reference assignment (`=&`) and there are important differences between the two.

Answer (score 1):

`$values['b']` didn't exist when you assigned it to `$values['a']`. If you change the order, it works as you describe:

```
~$ php -a
php > $values = array();
php > $values['c'] = 1;
php > $values['b'] = &$values['c'];
php > $values['a'] = &$values['b'];
php > print_r($values);
Array
(
    [c] => 1
    [b] => 1
    [a] => 1
)
```

Comment: This is intuitively reasonable, but incorrect: it is not the non-existence of `$values['b']` that is the problem, but the fact that it is re-pointed to a different value, leaving `$values['a']` still pointed at the old value.

Comment: The key misunderstanding is that there is a chain to travel - don't picture arrows going from variable to variable, picture arrows pointing inwards from lots of variables to the same place.

Comment: @IMSoP I removed my incorrect explanation. The fix with changing order still stands though.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: this answer is to [the question as originally asked](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19067482/1). The new question is somewhat different, although the use of objects doesn't change the fundamental behaviour in this case.

PHP references cannot be "chained" - the `=&` operator is not like a pointer reference/de-reference mechanism, it binds two (or more) variables together. But importantly neither variable name is more "real" than the other - they are *both* (or all) references to a *nameless value*.

For example, `$foo =& $bar` takes the value pointed at by `$bar` and **also** points `$foo` at that value. If you then assign to either variable (e.g. `$foo = 42;` or `$bar = 42;`), the value is updated.  Some actions, such as `unset($bar)` are acting on the *variable*, not the *value*, so they affect only that particular variable, not the referenced value.

You can see this in action by running this: `$foo = 42; $bar =& $foo; unset($foo); echo $bar;` Note that `$foo` was the "original" name for the value, but even after it is unset, the value still exists. You can then reuse the variable `$foo` for a completely different value, without affecting `$bar` in any way.

If you take a variable that was already a reference, and make it a reference to something else, that is like unsetting the reference and reusing the variable name to set a new one. So the *value* is unaffected, and previously referenced variable names become independent.

In your code, you do this:

```
// 1: Make $values['a'] point to the value currently pointed at by $values['b']
$values['a'] =& $values['b']; 
// 2: Make $values['b'] point to the value currently pointed at by $values['c']
//    the previous value is now only pointed to by $values['a']
$values['b'] =& $values['c']; 
// 3: Set the value shared by $values['b'] and $values['c'] to 1
$values['c'] = 1;
```

(As a technical detail, what I've been calling here "value" is a structure within PHP's internals called a `zval`.)

**Edit for updated question:**

Objects may seem to make this more complicated, as they have an *extra* level of indirection, which works in almost the same way: `$foo = new A('a'); $bar = $foo;` still creates two *values* (`zval`s) but those values are both pointers to the same *object*.

In your case, this makes no difference, as you are still using reference assignment (`=&`) - and if you didn't, you would get the same result:

```
// 1: Make the value of $values['a'] point to the object currently pointed at by the value of $values['b']
$values['a'] = $values['b']; 
// 2: Make the value of $values['b'] point to the object currently pointed at by the value of $values['c']
//    the previous object is now only pointed to by the value of $values['a']
$values['b'] = $values['c'];
```

We now have three things we can change: the *variable*, the *value* it points at, and the *object* that that points at:

```
// Change the object: updates the object shared by $values['b'] and $values['c']
$values['c']->value = 42;
// Change the value: will only update $values['b'] if =& was used to tie them together
$values['c'] = 42; 
// Change the variable: will never affect $values['b']
unset($values['c']);
```